# Android 4.2 filters out CHANGE_CONFIGURATION permission?

Tags: android

I come across a weird problem, I got an application allowing to freely change the font size on Android Device ([Font Size Setter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.gatay.android.fss%20%7C%20Font%20Size%20Setter)). It uses introspection to call some internal Android apis. To do this call, it needs the following permission : `android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION`. It worked like a charm under Android 4.0 and up to 4.2 where it does not work anymore. 
Digging into logs I found out that I can't update font size because it misses this permission. Debbuging to check effective permissions, I got these when inspecting the PackageInfo corresponding to my app

```
requestedPermissions = {java.lang.String[2]@830038778728}
    [0] = {java.lang.String@830038778760}"android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION"
    [1] = {java.lang.String@830038778896}"android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
requestedPermissionsFlags = {int[2]@830038779016}
    [0] = 1
    [1] = 3
```

Does somebody got any clue about what's going on, or any workaround idea ?
Thanks a lot for reading me.

Per request, the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="fr.gatay.android.fss"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you post the Manifest file?

Comment: I had the same problem on https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wiirecords.localizedapps. I added android:maxSdkVersion="16" to my manifest to filter newer android versions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least at present, `CHANGE_CONFIGURATION` requires for your app either to be signed by the firmware signing key or be installed on a system partition. You can see this by examining [the framework manifest](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml), where these permissions are defined.

Comment: Thanks, so I guess it is the dead of my application if I can't do this. Is there any known workaround ?

Comment: @CedricGatay: Well, you are using "introspection to call some internal Android apis" -- expecting that to work across releases is not very sensible. That being said, I have no idea what specifically you were using `CHANGE_CONFIGURATION` for.

Comment: basically I use `IActivityManager#updatePersistentConfiguration` to update the font size Android should use. I didn't find other ways to do so. I'd prefer using a public API though.

Comment: How would one go about procuring a firmware signing key? My org depends on this for an internal tool that sets a bogus locale for testing localization, and this is throwing a wrench in Jellybean QA.

Comment: @Cheezmeister: "How would one go about procuring a firmware signing key?" -- you have to build your own firmware. For example, CyanogenMod has some signing key for use in their ROM mod.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sir is there a workaround to this ? I have faced the same problem on 4.2 and 4.3 too.

Answer (score 5):

Check this post  http://blog.sightidea.com/?p=44

You can ask your user to grant permission to the app with `adb` tool:

```
>adb shell
>pm grant com.yourapp.packagename android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION
```

Answer (score 4):

The protection level of CHANGE_CONFIGURATION permission has been changed to "system|signature|development" (v4.2) from "dangerous" (v4.1 and below) since Android v4.2

It looks like that no way for 3rd part apps to get CHANGE_CONFIGURATION permission on Android 4.2+ devices. :-(