# Changing languages on an android device with ADB

Tags: android, internationalization, adb

So I came across the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712205/change-device-language-via-adb). The command:

```
adb shell "setprop persist.sys.language fr; setprop persist.sys.country CA; setprop ctl.restart zygote"
```

However after using this command I could no longer change the language with ADB again. I've tried other variations (even back to English to no avail). Such as:

```
adb shell "setprop persist.sys.language zh; setprop persist.sys.country CN; setprop ctl.restart zygote"

adb shell "setprop persist.sys.language es; setprop persist.sys.country ES; setprop ctl.restart zygote"

adb shell "setprop persist.sys.language en; setprop persist.sys.country US; setprop ctl.restart zygote"
```

Each command visibly did nothing. What am I missing here?

Comment: I would love to know the reason for the negative votes.

Comment: Please how can i add additional language for `HEBREW` Israel

Answer (score 0):

Are you on adb root?

I face the same issue and then moving to adb root and executing change language command works.

here is what I did:

```
adb root
adb shell "setprop persist.sys.language fr; setprop persist.sys.country CA; setprop ctl.restart zygote"
```