# How to get the id of a string resource associated with a TextView?

Tags: android, textview, android-resources

I can access the TextView instance, get it's resource ID and get it's resource name via `getResources().getResourceEntryName()`, but I can't seem to find a way to get the id of the string associated with it.

How can I dynamically get the id of the string resource associated with a TextView ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only workaround I could was to match the `+id` of the TextView instances in the layout xml with the `name` of the string, then use Resources to get pair the two:

```
/**
     * finds a string id matching a text view id name and returns the value
     * @param textView - text view
     * @param context  - the context
     * @param locale   - the locale string
     * @return  String - resource string if found, empty string otherwise
     */
    public  static String getTextViewStringFromResources(TextView textView,Context context,String locale){
        String result = "";
        final int textViewID = textView.getId();

        if(textViewID <= 0){
            Log.e(TAG,"invalid id for textView " + textView + " text = " + textView.getText());
            result = textView.getText().toString();
            return result;
        }
        //get resources (re-usable)
        final Resources resources = getLocalizedResources(context,locale);
        // get textViews id
        final String entryName = resources.getResourceEntryName(textView.getId());
        // get the string id !! must match the textview id !!
        final int stringID = resources.getIdentifier(entryName,"string",context.getPackageName());
        //return string value for string id found by textview id
        try{
            result = resources.getString(stringID);
        }catch (Resources.NotFoundException e){
            Log.e(TAG,"couldn't find a string id for " + entryName);
            Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }

//!! requires minSDK 17
    @NonNull
    public static Resources getLocalizedResources(Context context, String locale) {
        Locale desiredLocale = new Locale(locale);
        Configuration conf = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        conf.setLocale(desiredLocale);
        Context localizedContext = context.createConfigurationContext(conf);
        return localizedContext.getResources();
    }
```

The swapping is partially based on [Gunhan Sancar's method](https://gunhansancar.com/change-language-programmatically-in-android/) of swapping text field.

This works but it pretty much a hack.

Eventually I needed to also change the Google Handwriting Input language programmatically and for that [Juuso's ADB Change Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712205/change-device-language-via-adb/27758571#27758571) app came in super handy.

For reference, here's a function using Juuso's approach:

```
final String TAG = "ChangeLanguage"
//change language utils "kindly borrowed" from net.sanapeli.adbchangelanguage: brilliant little app!

    /**
     * updates a Configuration with a list of Locales
     * @param configuration - a configuration to updated
     * @param arrayList - an ArrayList of Locale instances
     * @return the updated configuration
     */
    @TargetApi(24)
    public static Configuration addLocalesToConfiguration(Configuration configuration, ArrayList<Locale> arrayList) {
        configuration.setLocales(new LocaleList((Locale[]) arrayList.toArray(new Locale[arrayList.size()])));
        return configuration;
    }

    /**
     * Change the system language
     * @param lanaguageList - a list of Locale instances to change to
     */
    public static void changeLanguages(ArrayList<Locale> lanaguageList){
        try {
            Class cls = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityManagerNative");
            Method method = cls.getMethod("getDefault", new Class[0]);
            method.setAccessible(true);
            Object invoke = method.invoke(cls, new Object[0]);
            method = cls.getMethod("getConfiguration", new Class[0]);
            method.setAccessible(true);
            Configuration configuration = (Configuration) method.invoke(invoke, new Object[0]);
            configuration.getClass().getField("userSetLocale").setBoolean(configuration, true);
            if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
                configuration = addLocalesToConfiguration(configuration, lanaguageList);
            } else {
                configuration.locale = (Locale) lanaguageList.get(0);
            }
            Method method2 = cls.getMethod("updateConfiguration", new Class[]{Configuration.class});
            method2.setAccessible(true);
            method2.invoke(invoke, new Object[]{configuration});
            Log.d(TAG,"locale updated to" + lanaguageList.get(0).toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"error changing locale (double check you're granted permissions to the app first: pm grant your.app.package.here android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION )");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Remember to grant `CHANGE_CONFIGURATION` to your app.

This is tested with Android 7.1.1 but bare in mind that it will fail on Android 8.0 (and potentially upwards) as `getConfiguration` is not found (the API is different) under certain build conditions.

The method expects an ArrayList of Locale objects with the language you want to change to on top:
e.g.

```
ArrayList<Locale> fr = new ArrayList<Locale>();
fr.add(new Locale("fr"));
fr.add(new Locale("en"));

ArrayList<Locale> en = new ArrayList<Locale>();
en.add(new Locale("en"));
en.add(new Locale("fr"));
```

Make sure the Languages are installed on the devices as well.

If you have other improvement suggestions I'd be more than happy to update the answer

Comment: this is nonsense since it works only if textview has same res name as string res

Comment: As I mentioned at the top: it's a hack (and not a pretty one, if there is such a thing) :) Totally agree with you on the res/string res. Also I don't like how it messes with the locale lists a user might have set in via OS settings. If you have something in mind it would be great if you could share a cleaner solution: please and thank you :D

Answer (score 2):

You can't. A `TextView` doesn't store the id of the String resources if you call `setText(int resid)`. All this overloaded method does is get the String from the resources and call the `setText(CharSequence text)` method.

Comment: Hmmm, that's no fun. Wish there was a way

Comment: I don't know what your use case is but I'm sure you can keep track of what String resource you last set to the TextView in your own code.

Comment: I'm swapping some locale strings without changing the full os settings, just internal to my app. Is there an after `setContentView` is called on an activity ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're trying to do. Are you trying to change the language in your app without changing the language of the entire phone?

Comment: That's right! So far I found [this](https://github.com/gunhansancar/ChangeLanguageExample), but the textviews and strings are hardcoded. I've started modifying the code and I can loop find TextView instances to swap text, but it would be great if I could make an activity superclass that did this as after onCreate, as soon as the extending activity called `setContentView` so the TextViews are present :)

Comment: So you're changing the text of the `TextViews` with different String resources (not languages) and you also want to let the user change the language, both during runtime?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157922/discussion-between-george-profenza-and-sander).

Comment: George Profenza! You very helped! Thank you!  +100! :)

Comment: Users can now choose which languages they want to use in specific apps. Not sure if it helps, but there's that.