# Android - How to get string key value from TextView in XML

Tags: android

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"/>

<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
```

i want to get the key "hello_world" dynamically during runtime in my fragment

Comment: You already have done in this line `android:text="@string/hello_world"`.

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari i want get the string key "hello_world", not the value of the string "Hello world!"

Comment: `String mystring = getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world);`. (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7493367/6523232)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the id of a string resource associated with a TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47035362/how-to-get-the-id-of-a-string-resource-associated-with-a-textview)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Resource Name from Resource id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137692/how-to-get-resource-name-from-resource-id)