# Get string resource name from TextView's text

Tags: android

I'd like to get string resource's name from a `TextView`. So for example I have a string in `strings.xml`:

```
<string name="my_text">Hello world</string>
```

and I set this text to a `TextView` via XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myAwesomeTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/my_text"/>
```

Now I need to get my string resource's name `my_text` programatically.

I can get text like so:

```
myAwesomeTextView.text //here I get: Hello world
```

And I can get `TextView`'s name like so:

```
resources.getResourceEntryName(myAwesomeTextView.id); //here I get: myAwesomeTextView
```

Is there a way to get string resource's name - in this case `my_text` via kotlin/java code

Comment: What do you want to get actually? The string resource name or the string resource value?

Comment: I need the string resource's name, in my case `my_text` from kotlin/Java

Comment: What! I'm surprised why do you need this! Can you tell me in what case you need this?

Comment: This seems the possible way using `final int stringID = resources.getIdentifier(entryName,"string",context.getPackageName());`, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47075068/8244632) code.

Comment: @LalitFauzdar this doesn't work, this will retrieve string res id if I know it's name, but I don't know it, I know textview id and name.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to say this is not possible. TextView never stores the resource id so it's name. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: nope, I need to get string res name, it means `your_string_id` from textview

Comment: Oh sorry now I understood. Now I've edited my answer.

Comment: If you could accept my answer then don't. But my answer isn't wrong, could you please tell me why did you downvoted my answer?