# how to give dynamic android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS permission on a board non UserInterface

Tags: android, selinux

I have installed application as a user mode and not rooted. Hence some of the android.permissions like write permission are ignored and not set. was able to identify from packages.xml and also from the command "adb shell dumpsys package "

I want to set write permission to the application that I installed to the device.
I have access to android OS code, Is there a way to grant the permission? either by sepolicy change??

Note : device is not UI(user interface)

Please help!!

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package=<package-name>
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"  tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <service android:name=<service-name>
            <intent-filter >
              ---
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: need to grant android permission to the application installed under /data/app/

Comment: I think you need to ask the user for permission at runtime.  https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6270602?hl=en

Comment: right, as this is not tablet application(UI), I want to know how to grant that from OS code.

Comment: @Knight have you found a solution for this? I have a Device Owner app but I am not able to grant WRITE_SETTINGS without user prompt

Answer (score 5):

On a rooted device you can use the following command:

```
adb shell appops set foo.bar.package WRITE_SETTINGS allow
```

Answer (score 1):

use this command `adb shell pm grant you package android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS`  and only system app and rooted app can write the setting but this command help you to write setting.

```
   public void setSettingsAutomaticDateTimeIfNeeded() {
    String timeZoneSettings = android.provider.Settings.Global.getString(
            this.getContentResolver(),
            android.provider.Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME_ZONE);
    Log.e(TAG, "auot update check true");
    if (timeZoneSettings.contentEquals("0")) {
        android.provider.Settings.Global.putString(
                this.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME_ZONE, "1");
        Log.e(TAG, "Auto update checked make true");
    }

    String timeSettings = android.provider.Settings.Global.getString(
            this.getContentResolver(),
            android.provider.Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME);
    Log.e(TAG, "auot update check true");
    if (timeSettings.contentEquals("0")) {
        android.provider.Settings.Global.putString(
                this.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME, "1");
        Log.e(TAG, "Auto update checked make true");
    }
}
```

and add this inot manifest

```
 <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

Comment: I tried the same, as it is non rooted application I am getting following error.      Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS is not a changeable permission type.          and yes,I am looking for WRITE_SETTINGS.

Comment: Edited my description and added manifest file. I am trying to set wifi ssid data via application, which is not allowing me to write those setting into it, as my is a user application. which stored in /data/app.

Comment: As android document these are only worked in rooted device and system app..

Comment: This actually works, but you need to disable permission checks in developer options, as described in the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52079343/how-can-i-use-adb-to-grant-permission-without-root