# Testing locale-specific behavior on 4.2+ devices

Tags: android, android-permissions

Now that [Google has broken android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440045/android-4-2-filters-out-change-configuration-permission), how are developers and QA techs supposed to test locale-specific behavior?

My 4.4 device offers English, French, Spanish, and Portuguese.  I've done some testing in Arabic on older devices, and I'm sure I'll run into another scenario like that sooner or later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can allow locale changing also on newer (4.2+) devices:
`adb shell pm grant <your_app_package_name> android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION`

I could find no documentation, but there are a couple of issues filed to Google:

- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56519 (closed without explanation)

> Changing the system language via ActivityManagers updateConfiguration() requires the permission android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION.
>   Unfortunatelly, the protectionLevel of that permission has changed from 1 ("dangerous", up to Android 4.1) to 0x12 ("signature | system", in Android 4.2).

- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=92866

Comment: I'll accept this answer if you define "newer devices" and provide a link to documentation.

Comment: Heh, that second issue was created by me.