# Ask multiples permissions android 6.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, permissions, android-permissions

I have to show multiple permissions and my program just show the first one i dont know why, i hope you can help me

*IMPORTS*

```
import static android.Manifest.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION;
import static android.Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS;
import static android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE; 
import static android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS;
```

*MAIN*

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    Permis();
}
```

*Function Permis*

```
private void Permis() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if ((checkSelfPermission(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ==  PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) &&
            (checkSelfPermission(CHANGE_CONFIGURATION) ==  PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) &&
            (checkSelfPermission(MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS) ==  PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) &&
            (checkSelfPermission(WRITE_SETTINGS) ==  PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

            Toast.makeText(tuneActivity.this, "Permiso concedido  anteriormente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if ((shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))||
            (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(CHANGE_CONFIGURATION)) || 
            (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS)) || 
            (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(WRITE_SETTINGS))) {

            DialogoAlerta();

        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,  CHANGE_CONFIGURATION, MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS, WRITE_SETTINGS},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}
```

*Function DialogoAlerta*

```
private void DialogoAlerta() {

        AlertDialog.Builder dialogo=new AlertDialog.Builder(tuneActivity.this);
        dialogo.setTitle("Permisos desactivados");
        dialogo.setMessage("Debe aceptar los permisos para poder definir un  tono como ringtone o sonido de notificacion");
        dialogo.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,  CHANGE_CONFIGURATION, MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS, WRITE_SETTINGS},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
                }
            }

        });
    }
```

*onRequestPermissionsResult*

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] ==
                 PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] ==
                 PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[2] ==
                 PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[3] ==
                 PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) { 
                    Toast.makeText (tuneActivity.this,"Permiso concedido",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText (tuneActivity.this,"Permiso no concedido",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        return;
    }
}
```

}

So.. the program just ask for the first permission'Write External Storage' and then it's shows 'permiso no concedido' but i dont know why, i hope you can explain me why, thanks and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permission request is only required for the permissions whose protection level is `dangerous`. You can refer this [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) to determine the protection level. Refer this [permission overview document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview.html) for more details.

### **`MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS`**

You don't see permission request for this because the protection level for this permission is `normal`. This permission will be granted automatically without need of requesting to user.

### **`WRITE_SETTINGS`**

You don't see permission request because the protection level is `signature`. Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_SETTINGS):

> **Note:** If the app targets API level 23 or higher, the app user must explicitly grant this permission to the app through a permission management screen. **The app requests the user's approval by sending an intent with action ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS.** The app can check whether it has this authorization by calling Settings.System.canWrite().

You need to fire intent to request this permission.

### **`CHANGE_CONFIGURATION`**

This permission requires app to be signed by firmware signing key or be installed on a system partition. So you cannot request this permission through permission dialog. Refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440045/android-4-2-filters-out-change-configuration-permission)

However there is a workaround to grant this permission though `adb` as follows:

`adb -d shell pm grant <your package name> android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION`

But you cannot expect all your users to have technical knowledge to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Sagar said, the only permission that i have to request is the "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" because the "MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" is just considered "normal" for android. But returning to my problem one solution that i found is that:

the "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" just asking it like i did, and in order to get the WRITE_SETTINGS i do that code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        retVal = Settings.System.canWrite(this);
if(retVal){  
            Toast.makeText(this, "All good", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(intent); // we open the part of the system configuration in which the person have to just enable our app ;)
        }
```