# Android app is supported by 0 devices in Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, build.gradle, android-manifest, google-play-console

After the upload of my apk on the Google Play Developer Console my app is supported by 0 devices. Where is my error here?

I've tested it on my testing device and it works very well....

**My AndroidManifest file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.megalnt.elmeloratprinter">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"

        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <service
            android:name="com.megalnt.elmeloratprinter.FloatingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"/>
        <service
            android:name="com.megalnt.elmeloratprinter.BluetoothConnectService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"/>

        <activity

            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**build.gradle**

[gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8NiJ.png)

Comment: Add gradle file also.

Comment: Yeah what @DennyDog said. Please add your app.gradle file so we can have a look at your build, target and compile sdk

Comment: @DennyDog this is my gradle file https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8NiJ.png

Comment: Maybe this thread can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020237/android-app-is-supported-by-0-devices

Comment: @DennyDog this thread not working for me.

Comment: It may be due to android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION [Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440045/android-4-2-filters-out-change-configuration-permission)

Comment: I removed all permission. But it showing same problem.....